# Page orientation in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing, orientation

I want to print my document in Silverlight 4 with PrintDocument. But I want to use Landscape orientation of paper. I use code like this:

```
public Run()
{
    var pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(pd_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}

void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageVisual = myPaper;
}
```

We can use PrintPageEventArgs for modification page print. But we can't PrintPageEventArgs.PrintableArea (PrintableArea always use portrait orientation). What I can do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue and decided that silverlight has no way of access to the printer dialog (as it is sandboxed) so we documented this feature and let our users set the orientation in the printer dialog and inside the application. this way, the printout is correct, but this is really ugly.
I would appreciate anyone knowing a better solution to this!